# Unable to reset form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, reset

I'm using three different methods to reset my form, but still nothing happens after I click the buttons, Here is my form's structure:
*Any help would be appreciated*

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$attributes = array('class' => 'form-inline', 'id' => 'ProductForm');
echo form_open_multipart("product/process/$id",$attributes);
.
.
.
<?php echo  form_reset(array('id'=>'reset','value'=>'resetme'));?>        
<button onclick="ResetForm();">Reset Form</button>
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
<?php echo form_close();?>
<script>
function ResetForm() {
    document.getElementById("ProductForm").reset() ;
}
</script>
//same for form_open()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mahdi Younesi: Just use the input type reset and then test it will reset the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

first add some input types in form to test the reset function

here is the solution

add one input in form and than

replace form_reset(array('id'=>'reset')); to  form_reset(array('id'=>'reset','value'=>"resetme"));

Comment: Thanks, but I had given value  before ,but didn't  mention  before